# AddListMembersListRequest does not add records

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

AddListMembersListRequest does not add all records in dynamics CRM 2011 marketing list.

I am using below function to add provided member guid into crm 2011 marketing list , but it add one record less.
For example : if memberGuidList count is 100 it adds 99 records.

```
private void AddMembersToMarketingList(Guid thisListGuid, List<Guid> memberGuidList, IOrganizationService gCRMService)
{
     AddListMembersListRequest orgServiceRequest = new AddListMembersListRequest();
     orgServiceRequest.ListId = thisListGuid;
     orgServiceRequest.MemberIds = memberGuidList.ToArray();
     gCRMService.Execute(orgServiceRequest);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several possible answers:

1. In case you don't get an exception it could be that you pass an id of inactive record on one hand and you check active record view from marketing list.
2. In case you get an exception - recheck it. Is there a chance that you pass duplicated id or id that doesn't have correspond record in CRM (or record was deleted)?

Comment: Actually I figured that "memberGuidList" has some duplicate GUID , so I used .Distinct().ToList() to get the distinct GUID.

Comment: So number 2 answers your question. Mark it as an answer.